# How to change display name for areas, controllers and actions in view in ASP.NET Core identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I want to create a dynamic identity for roles that admin can add access to roles. I created it and it works fine but in the view it shows the actual name for each areas, controllers and actions. I want to change these names to another language for displaying but I want to insert the actual names in table. How should I do that? I searched a lot but I couldn't find any solution.

This is the class and method that returns the names of all areas and controllers and actions:

```
public class MvcUtilities : IMvcUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Will add all area and controller and action names into a List of tuple.
    /// </summary>
    public MvcUtilities(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actionDescriptorCollectionProvider)
    {
        var actionDescriptors = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider.ActionDescriptors.Items;
        foreach (var actionDescriptor in actionDescriptors)
        {
            var descriptor = actionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            if (descriptor == null) continue;

            var controllerTypeInfo = descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo;
            //var actionMethodInfo = descriptor.MethodInfo;

            ValueTuples.Add((controllerTypeInfo.GetCustomAttribute<AreaAttribute>()?.RouteValue,
                descriptor.ControllerName,
                descriptor.ActionName));
        }
    }

    public IList<(string areaName, string controllerName, string actionName)> ValueTuples { get; }
        = new List<(string areaName, string controllerName, string actionName)>();

    public IList<ActionAndControllerName> AreaAndActionAndControllerNamesList()
    {
        var list = ValueTuples.Distinct().Select(t => new ActionAndControllerName()
        {
            AreaName = t.areaName,
            ControllerName = t.controllerName+"Controller",
            ActionName = t.actionName
        });

        return list.Where(l=>(l.ControllerName!="AccountController")&&(l.ActionName!="Management"))
            
     
 .OrderByDescending(ar=>ar.AreaName).ThenBy(c=>c.ControllerName).ThenBy(a=>a.ActionName).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This is just your design to manage the actions, so basically it's not related to Identity at all. You have the original info (action name, controller name, area name), if you want to display some friendly or translated names, just declare a service to convert/transform the names. This can even be simplified to the problem of localization or translation.